# Modify both key and value in a LinkedHashMap without affecting the insertion order

Tags: java, collections

I read lines from a file and load them into a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order.  At a certain point of my algorithm I have to modify both a key and it's corresponding value without affecting the insertion order. Here is an example :

This is the initial content of my `LinkedHashMap`

```
"k1" -> "v1"
"k2" -> "v2"
"k3" -> "v3"
"k4" -> "v4"
"k5" -> "v5"
```

I want to modify `k3` and `v3` so that I get :

```
"k1" -> "v1"
"k2" -> "v2"
"k33" -> "v33"
"k4" -> "v4"
"k5" -> "v5"
```

But if I use

```
map.remove("k3");
map.put("k33", "v33");
```

Then what I get instead is :

```
"k1" -> "v1"
"k2" -> "v2"
"k4" -> "v4"
"k5" -> "v5"
"k33" -> "v33"
```

Which is a perfectly normal behavior, but not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Why don't you use a `List` of `Pairs` if order is what matters to you?

Comment: You can't modify a key in a Map without removing it.  You need to preserve order in a different collection if this is what you want. e.g. a List of keys

Comment: Order is not the only thing that matters to me, I need also to be able to search for a key efficiently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the order of the enteries is important, I'd keep a separate list that maintains that order - this will make it obvious to anyone subsequently looking at your code what's going on.

Comment: But If I do so, then I need to update that separate list whenever I call the put method. And to update that list I need to search for the key (and the list is big). Do you think it would still be efficient ?

Comment: I'd put the two update calls in a method and just call that method when an update is required.  With regards to efficiency, first make it work, then make it fast if you see a performance problem.  If there's IO involved manipulation of a list is unlikely to be the performance bottle neck.

Answer (score 8):

If performance is not critical, I could offer a workaround

```
public class ReplaceLinkedHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    public void replace(K oldKey, K newKey, V newValue) {
        LinkedHashMap<K, V> tmp = new LinkedHashMap<>(this);
        clear();
        for (Entry<K, V> e : tmp.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().equals(oldKey)) {
                put(newKey, newValue);
            } else {
                put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```